# Finding duplicates from multiple number of arguments

Tags: javascript, duplicates

So basically I have this function:

```
function areThereDuplicates(a,b,c,d) {
  if (typeof d === 'undefined') { d = 'default'; }
  let arr = new Array(a,b,c,d)
  if(arr.length == 0){
      return false
  }

  let counter = {};

  for (let i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
      let digit = arr[i];
      counter[digit] ? counter[digit] += 1 : counter[digit] = 1
  }

   let values = Object.values(counter)
   for (let i = 0 ; i < values.length; i++){
     if(values[i] != 1){
       return true
     }
   }
  return false

}
```

It works fine with a maximum of 4 parameters for the function. How can I create another variable or something to assume the number of parameters could go up to n and at the same time to add the exact elements to the new array 'arr'.

Or even better, how can I escape the use of creating a new array to take the parameters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function includes an array-like variable called `arguments` which contains all the arguments. You can just spread that out to get your array.

```
function areThereDuplicates() {
    arr = [...arguments];
    // ...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function areThereDuplicates() {
  let arr = [...arguments]
  if(arr.length == 0){
      return false
  }

  let counter = {};

  for (let i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
      let digit = arr[i];
      counter[digit] ? counter[digit] += 1 : counter[digit] = 1
  }

   let values = Object.values(counter)
   for (let i = 0 ; i < values.length; i++){
     if(values[i] != 1){
       return true
     }
   }
  return false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides that you can use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), as the other answer suggests (but contrary to the suggestion, you can simply use it directly with your code, it has`[]` and `length`), you could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Then the function could become

```
function areThereDuplicates() {
  return arguments.length !== new Set(arguments).size;
}
```

---

However, speaking of complexity: for a yes/no answer your loop could `return` immediately when it encounters a duplicate. Finding more duplicates will not produce a "stronger" `true`:

```
function areThereDuplicates() {
  for(let i=0; i<arguments.length-1; i++) {
    let current=arguments[i];
      for(let j=i+1; j<arguments.length; j++)
        if(current===arguments[j])
          return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And then you can combine the two (`Set` with early `return` - also, runnable snippet, the others were sent from phone):

```js
function areThereDuplicates() {
  console.log(arguments);
  let set=new Set();
  for(let item of arguments){
    if(set.has(item))
      return true;
    set.add(item);
  }
  return false;
}

function doThing(event) {
  result.innerText=areThereDuplicates(...event.target.value.split(","));
}

doThing({target:document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="a,b,b" oninput="doThing(event)">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that too. What's the O() for the set method?

Comment: @octaviandd worst case complexity is similar to your loops. Just `Set`s are hash set usually (better lookup performance on average), and `Set()` is native code, does not wait for JIT.